# Webgrid generating 'data-swhglnk' makes it impossible to use arrows for sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

As the title of this question says I'm unable to add the arrows to my webgrid when data-swhglnk='true' is present on my link, which is autogenerated by Webgrid. I have searched for this attribute but none explains me how I can modify this attribute in the Webgrid.

The attribute 'data-swhglnk' avoids the link of updating in my browser. However the link does allow me to sort the data which I experience as strange because the sorting works on this link aswell.

How can I change the 'data-swhglnk' attribute to false with the creation of my Webgrid?

Here is some code i'm using to generate the Webgrid.

### Code

```
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.invList, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid", ajaxUpdateCallback: "webGridUpdated");

    @grid.GetHtml(  htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },

                    columns:new []{
                        grid.Column(header: "Header1", format: @<text> @if (@item.viewed != true){ <span class="new"> false </span> } else{<span> true </span>}</text>),
                        grid.Column(header: "Header2", format:@<text><input name="downloads" type="checkbox" value="@item.invoiceRefUID" /></text>),
                        grid.Column("invoiceDate", header: "Header3", format: (item) => String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", item.invoiceDate)
})
```

When I change the attribute to false in my debugger of my browser and then hit the sort link the arrows appear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

afaik, this attribute 'data-swhglnk' is true and appear when you specify/use the parameter ajaxUpdateContainerId in the WebGrid constructor, telling it to use ajax behavior.

if you omit the ajaxUpdateContainerId, 'data-swhglnk' doesn't show up.